# How to prove $(1+q)^n \geq1+qn$ for all $\mathbb{N}$ with $q>0$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, inequality, induction

I need to prove $(1+q)^n \geq1+qn$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ with $q>0, q\in \mathbb{R}$ using mathematical induction.

Firstly, I proved the base case for $n=1$ that indeed $1+q\geq1+q$.

Then in the inductive step, I started with $(1+q)^{k+1}$ and came to the following form $(1+q)^k(1+q)\geq(1+qk)(1+q)$. However I'm uncertain how to *explicitly* show that $(1+q)^{k+1}\geq1+q(k+1)$ because after the expansion I get the $kq^2$ term that I'm unable to get rid of.

I would appreciate any help! Thank you!

Comment: $kq^2>0$ since $q>0$ :-)

Comment: To clarify,  $n\in {\mathbb{N}}$, correct?

Comment: Normally, in math writing,$n$ and $N$ are different variables. Do you mean them to be the same?

Comment: Or maybe you meant “for all $n\in\mathbb N.$

Comment: Thank you for your replies! Yes, I meant natural numbers. I have $1+q(1+k)+qk^2$  in my notes but is knowing $q^2k\geq0$ enough to just discard the term from the right side?

Comment: @DrMaps so you are restricting $n$ to natural numbers?

Comment: @RadialArmSaw yes, $n \in \mathbb{N}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can actually do the whole same process by admitting that $q>-1$. The calculations could be organized a little more neatly:

$$\begin{align*}
(1+q)^{k+1}&=(1+q)(1+q)^k\\
&\ge(1+q)(1+kq)\\
&=1+(k+1)q+kq^2\\
&\ge 1+(k+1)q\;,
\end{align*}$$

since $kq^2\ge 0$. This completes the induction step. This result is known as the Bernoulli's inequality.